# MDIForm gives error 7 not enough memory in new computers but not in old

Tags: vba, forms, memory, mdi

An **MDIForm** application that **works** perfectly in several computers **doesn't work in new ones**. I'm not 100% sure but I think it's built on **Visual Basic 6**.

The application **works while you have only one form**, the **problem** is when you **open several** forms. Then it gives the following message:

**Error 7** during execution time: not enough memory

This application is **very old**, so I **don't have the source code** and there's no way to contact the programmer. It has a small **installation program**, so if the application is working in other computers and it doesn't in new ones, **maybe** one of the **libraries** it installs is **corrupt**. What I need is to **locate** which library is **giving me problems** and download it, to check if the problem is solved.

There are **several** dll and ocx **files** in a cabinet, which is a lossless compression file for Windows. I'm searching for **all files on Google**, here's the **list**:

***Note:*** removed those that weren't even present in a computer where the application works, added them at the end of the message

**COMCAT.DLL** -> module associated with Microsoft(R) Windows NT(R) Operating System

**oleaut32.dll** -> library which contains core OLE functions

**RICHED32.DLL** -> module containing functions for the Rich Text Edit control

**stdole2.tlb** -> defines certain interfaces and type you can use

Do you know what could be happening? **Thank you for your time**.

Regards,

David

**edit 1**: added all searches. I'm **trying** a "sfc /scannow" in a new computer to check if it's magically solved, but I don't think so. **Any ideas?** Any **help** will be greatly appreciated

**edit 2**: sfc /scannow found problems, but the **application still doesn't work**. I'm trying now to install it in a **virtual machine** with Virtual Box and Windows XP, but I **always** get the the **same error**.

**edit 3**: I tried to **use the installer** to **override the DLLs** in a computer **where the application worked**. Well, the application **still works** like a charm, so now I'm completely lost and I don't know what else I can do. I tried to **install the last .NET** in a computer where the **application didn't work, it still doesn't**. It would make no sense if it worked after that, but I had no idea what to try now.

**edit**: rest of files that aren't even present in a computer where the application works:

asycfilt.dll -> module used by Microsoft OLE (Object Linking and Embedding)

CMDLGES.DLL -> DLL file created by Microsoft Corporation

comdlg32.ocx -> used for showing common dialogs like open or save

cpvCoolList.ocx -> no idea, maybe it's a rich list box or something

DAO350.DLL -> module associated with Microsoft® Jet

DiCtrlTransp.ocx -> no idea

expsrv.dll -> file that contains functions to work with VBA Run-time - Expression Service

FLXGDES.DLL -> used by MSFlexGrid created by Microsoft Corporation

FM20.DLL -> module providing applications with functions to create forms

MDAC_TYP.EXE -> process associated with Microsoft(R) Windows (R) 2000 Operating System

msado21.tlb -> Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Library

MSCC2ES.DLL -> module associated with MSCANDUI Server DLL from Microsoft

MSCMCES.DLL -> ActiveX Windows Common Controls

mscomct2.ocx -> ActiveX control module that contains common controls used by Windows, such as Animation, UpDown, MonthView, DTPicker, and FlatScrollBar controls

mscomctl.ocx -> ActiveX Control module that contains common controls used by Windows, such as ImageCombo, ImageList, ListView, ProgressBar, Slider, StatusBar, TabStrip, ToolBar, and TreeView controls

msflxgrd.ocx -> Microsoft FlexGrid Control

MSJET35.DLL -> main component of the Microsoft Jet database engine which evaluates and carries out requests for data. The file handles reading and writing of the data for Microsoft Access databases. For non-native data, then the file makes calls to either the ODBC Driver Manager DLL or one of the external installable ISAM DLLs

MSJINT35.DLL -> no idea

MSJTER35.DLL -> module required by the Microsoft Jet Engine to operate correctly. The file provides error service for the Microsoft Jet database engine

MSRD2X35.DLL -> no idea

MSREPL35.DLL -> module used by the Microsoft Internet Ratings and Local User Management

msvbvm60.dll -> module for the Microsoft Visual Basic virtual machine

MSVCRT40.DLL -> module containing standard C library functions such as printf, memcpy, and cos. It is a part of the Microsoft C Runtime Library

olepro32.dll -> library which contains core OLE functions

Photo.ocx -> module belonging to Facebook Photo Uploader 4 from The Facebook

RCHTXES.DLL -> part of RichText control. Is ES for "Español" or Spanish?

RICHTX32.OCX -> module for the Microsoft Rich Text OLE Control and provides advanced editing capability for the TextBox object

ST6UNST.EXE -> process associated with Microsoft® Visual Basic for Windows from Microsoft Corporation

TABCTES.DLL -> module belonging to "Biblioteca de objetos" (objects library) TabCtl32 from Microsoft

TABCTL32.OCX -> ActiveX control module which contains SSTab control used for Tabbed Dialog Control

VB5DB.DLL -> Visual Basic ICursor Interface Library

VB6ES.DLL -> DLL file used by "Recursos internacionales del entorno Visual Basic" (Visual Basicl environment international resources) created by Microsoft Corporation

VB6STKIT.DLL -> module that contains application programming interface (API) functions that enable Visual Basic applications to create shortcuts (Shell Links) programmatically

vbajet32.dll -> module that contains application programming interface (API) functions to load the Visual Basic for Applications development environment

Comment: OLE is old. really old... frankly i'm surprised it still works at all.

Comment: Yes it is and yes, I'm also surprised it works in "old" Windows 10 machines.

Answer (score 0):

After checking all programs installed in a computer where the application works I realized I don't have installed Office 2003. Even I thought it made no sense I tried to install it and now... the application works. How can this be possible? Anyone knows what could be happening? Is there any log I could check to see what changed?

Anyway it works now, thanks everyone for reading me.